# Can't return array<int^, 2>^ c++/cli

Tags: c++-cli

I am trying to use this method:

```
array<int^,2>^ Function1()
{
return gcnew array<int^,2>{ { 1 }, { 2 }};
}
```

by typing:

```
auto x = Function1();
```

but I get an error:
Exception thrown at 0x73572A55 (clr.dll) in Project1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000834.

How to solve this problem if I want to keep the returning type?
Thanks!

Comment: A crash like this is caused by memory corruption.  The traditional mistake is assuming that it has something to do with the function being called.  But it is merely the victim and the corruption was caused by code that ran earlier.  Notable as well is that it is the GC heap that is corrupted, that's not a good problem to have.  Clearly nobody here can tell you where the bad code might live, you'll have to find it yourself.  Probably best to focus on interop code, where ever you call native C or C++ code and pass a pointer to managed data.

Answer (score 2):

`int` is not a reference type, and should not be used with `^`.

If you remove the `^` from `int^`, this code does run:

```
array<int, 2>^ Function1()
{
    return gcnew array<int, 2>{ { 1 }, { 2 } };
}
```

Comment: I know it will run but it is inherited, poorly written code and if I change the type I will have to modify many other places in the code. The fact is that this code could be run some time ago and that somehow worked. Is there a possiblity that after visual studio update this: 
auto x = Function1();
no longer works?

Comment: @BlueCompany the only other think I could suggest would be to skip the `auto` and see if that makes any difference, but `int^` is just not correct and should be changed.

Answer (score 2):

> How to solve this problem if I want to keep the returning type?

This return type is improper. There's no way to represent `int^` in C#, and probably not in other .Net languages either. Having a variable of type `int^` is a performance hit for each access of the integer, and I believe it's more work for the garbage collector as well.

The proper fix is to change `int^` to `int` *everywhere*.

---

Now, that said, I cannot reproduce the error you're getting. Perhaps your error is elsewhere.

```
array<int^,2>^ Function1()
{
    return gcnew array<int^,2>{ { 1 }, { 2 }};
}

int main(array<System::String^>^ args)
{
    auto x = Function1();
    Debug::WriteLine(x[0,0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
1
```